# I'm trying to create a df column based on contents of another column

Tags: python

I want to create a column based on the presence of specific sub-strings within another string column.

Sample Data:

```
Col0   Col1    Col2     Col3    UW_Path
Y      Y       Yes     AUWPNS   FL
Y      Y       Yes     N        FL
Y      N       No      N        FL-TRAD
Y      N      Yes      AUWPNS   FL-AU-Undefined
Y      N      Yes      N        FL-TRAD
Y      N      Yes      NRAPUW   FL-RAP
Y      N      Yes      Y        FL-AU
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ex_path = pd.read_csv('express_path_summary_derive.csv', index_col=None)

print(ex_path.head())

def summ_path(uwpath):
    if 'AU' in uwpath:
        return 'Algo Straight Through'
    elif 'RAP' in uwpath:
        return 'Rapid Approval Process'
    elif 'Undefined' in uwpath:
        return 'UW Path Not Set'
    else:
        return 'Fluidless'

ex_path['Summary_UW_Path'] = summ_path(ex_path['UW_Path'])

print(ex_path.head())
```

Expected `Summary_UW_Path` to show results per conditions.
The actual result is all values of `Summary_UW_Path` show 'Fluidless'.

Comment: `ex_path['Summary_UW_Path'] = ex_path['UW_Path'].apply(summ_path)`, see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html

Comment: Thanks.  Understand now that I was telling Python to perform the operation on the entire column rather than row by row.  Since it was a single column, would map have also worked?